# Calculation of this integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$z$ is a positive real number
$$F(z)=\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{\cos^4(x) \ln(1+z^2 \cos^2(x))}{1+z^2 \cos^2(x)} \, dx$$
In the aim to simplify the calculation , i first make a derivative of $F(z)$ with respect to z
$$F^{'}(z)=-\frac{2}{z} F(z)+\frac{2}{z} \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{\cos^2(x) \ln(1+z^2 \cos^2(x))}{(1+z^2 \cos^2(x))^2} dx+\frac{2\pi}{z^5}\left(z^2-5+\frac{5z^2+4}{\left(1+z^2\right)^{3/2}}\right)   $$
After that i don't know how to complete the computations. Please help me to compute this integral.

Comment: What have you tried…

Comment: Integrating with regards to $x$ or $z$?

Comment: This question is a little ill-posed. Is $z$ a constant? Do you mean $\cos(x^2)$ or $\cos^2(x)$?

Comment: I assume they mean $\cos^2(x)$ and integrating with respect to $dx$, because then this is an easy problem.

Comment: Please explain what you've tried, where you're stuck, and where this problem comes from. Otherwise it just looks like you're asking us to do your homework for you, and that's not what we do here at MSE.

Answer (score 1):

For any $A\in\mathbb{R}^+$

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log(1+A\cos^2\theta)\,d\theta = -\pi\log 2+\log\left(1+\sqrt{1+A}\right)\tag{1}$$

and

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log^2(1+A\cos^2\theta)\cos^2\theta\,d\theta &=& \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2 H_{n-1}}{n}(-1)^n A^n\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\cos\theta\right)^{2n+2}\,d\theta \\&=&\pi\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_{n-1}}{n 4^n}(-1)^n A^n \binom{2n+2}{n+1}\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$

so by differentiating both sides of $(2)$ with respect to $A$ we get
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^4(\theta)\log(1+A\cos^2\theta)}{1+A\cos^2\theta}\,d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_{n-1}}{4^n}A^{n-1}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}.\tag{3} $$

The harmonic-binomial series in the RHS of $(3)$ can be evaluated by exploiting $H_n=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\,dx$ and $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}z^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}}$, with the help of a CAS. Then you just have to replace $A$ with $z^2$ and exploit the periodicity of $\cos^2 x$ to get a closed form for $F(z)$.